# Help plotting the population growth and decline of a fictional race

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

I'm hoping this might be an appropriate place to ask for help in examining the rise and fall of a fantasy species I have in mind for a work of fiction. Ultimately I would like to be able to create a spreadsheet that allows me to plug in different numbers to produce a chart that will show the growth and decline of this race over time.

---

My species (and this is fantasy, remember) reproduces asexually. At year 0 one of these beings literally comes into existence. It is incredibly long lived (*a variable; about 3000 years*) and during its many fertile years (*variable; a %age of its total lifespan*) produces many offspring (*variable; maybe one every 2-3 years*).

These offspring, however, are not so long lived (*a %age decline; maybe 2800 years*) and don't produce as many offspring (*a smaller %age decline*).

I'm leaving out a lot of potentially relevant details (plague, famine, war, etc.), but just getting the basic shape of this on a chart will really help me fill out the backstory.

---

Apologies if this is all really basic / not appropriate for this SE. Needless to say, I'm out of my depth and would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Even to get a rough general idea you need to decide one thing right away: how does the lifespan decrease? One possibility is that each generation has a mean lifespan that is a fixed percentage (e.g., $90$%) of that of the previous generation.

Comment: Thanks Brian. That's actually one of the variables I'd like to be able to adjust to see what effect it has on things. But as a starting point, 90% sounds about right to me.

Comment: I actually wasn’t asking about a particular percentage, but rather whether you were thinking of this kind of geometric decrease (as opposed, say, to subtracting a constant number of years with each generation, so that eventually you’d reach a non-viable generation).

Comment: Aha. Indeed, my idea is that the species would gradually go extinct, unless something changed. My story takes place some time before that happens, but when they know it is inevitable.

Comment: Did a simulation in Excel. Assuming the species becomes fertile at a constant age of 20 years, stays fertile for 50% of their remaining lifespan, that each generation's lifespan is 95% of their parent, that each generation's fecundity is 95% of their parent, that the first being lives 3000 years and has a kid every 3 years while fertile,*then* the species dies out around the year 29,356. This is fairly simple to do if one monitors when the youngest child of each generation dies. The running total of the population size is a tougher challenge which I'm working on.

Comment: …And yes, I suppose I was imagining a geometric decrease of some kind. Each generation would be inferior to the one before, even if only by a few percentage points.

Comment: Jens, thank you. I'm very interested to see how this all works. 30,000 years is actually about perfect for my story needs too.